# Calculate the lengths of rules (in LaTeX3?)

Tags: latex3, calculations, dimensions

I don't think this hard to do but I 'am a real noob with calculations and dimensions.

In the code above I would like to calculate automatically the dimensions of the left and right rules such as leaving 20% of the line width unruled on both left and right side.
If a LaTeX3 version is possible, it would be great for me.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\newcommand\docruler[1]{%
    \begin{center}
        \color{green!50!black}%
        \scriptsize%
        \itshape\bfseries%
        \rule{.25\linewidth}{2.5pt}% <-- Calc. here.
        \,\,#1\,\,%
        \rule{.25\linewidth}{2.5pt}% <-- Calc. here.
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\docruler{ABCDEFGH}

\docruler{ABCDEFGH}

\docruler{XYZ}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following explicitly calculates the widths by first typesetting the argument into a box and measuring that box.

I've loaded the `showframe` package just so one can estimate the 20% of the line width being free.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_projetmbc_tmpa_box
\dim_new:N \l_projetmbc_rule_dim
\NewDocumentCommand \docruler { m }
  {
    \begin {center}
      \scriptsize\itshape\bfseries
      \hbox_set:Nn \l_projetmbc_tmpa_box { \,\, #1 \,\, }
      \dim_set:Nn \l_projetmbc_rule_dim
        { .3\linewidth - .5\box_wd:N \l_projetmbc_tmpa_box }
      \rule { \dim_use:N \l_projetmbc_rule_dim } { 2.5pt }
      \box_use:N \l_projetmbc_tmpa_box
      \rule { \dim_use:N \l_projetmbc_rule_dim } { 2.5pt }
    \end {center}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\docruler{ABCDEFGH}

\docruler{ABCDEFGH}

\docruler{XYZ}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this LaTeX3 version. What is the advantage to use `showframe`?

Comment: @projetmbc you see the page margins in form of a frame drawn on the paper. That's the only useful thing the package does.

Comment: I code too much today and my brain is melting... I have to go outside before asking another "stupid" question.  :-) Thanks for all!